# Swift 3.0 GameCenter matchmaking keeps cancelling after matching (issue converting objective-c to swift)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, game-center

I'm following the RayWenderlich GameCenter Tutorial: [Raywend GameCenter Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/60980/game-center-tutorial-how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-with-sprite-kit-part-1) but I'm trying to convert it into Swift 3.0. Basically all it does is authenticate the local player, open the matchmaking interface, and then it should call the `matchmakerViewController` function once two players find each other. 
The player is successfully authenticated, and the matchmakerViewController is presented, and the players find each-other. However, after displaying the opponent that it found and putting the blue checkmark next to their name, the app calls `matchmakerViewControllerWasCancelled` instead of `matchmakerViewController(viewController: GKMatchmakerViewController,didFindMatch match: GKMatch)` This is weird to me since I'm pretty sure that method is only called based on user interaction (it's not calling the error method).
 Running the objective-c version of the project works, but my swift conversion has this problem. Here are the two versions of the `findMatchWithMinPlayers()` method. I'm assuming I converted something wrong here:

**Swift**

```
func findMatchWithMinPlayers(minPlayers: Int, maxPlayers: Int, viewController: UIViewController, delegate: GameKitHelperDelegate) {
        if !enableGameCenter {
            return
        }
        self.matchStarted = false
        self.match = nil
        self.delegate = delegate
        viewController.dismiss(animated: false, completion: { _ in })
        var request = GKMatchRequest()
        request.minPlayers = minPlayers
        request.maxPlayers = maxPlayers
        var mmvc = GKMatchmakerViewController(matchRequest: request)
        mmvc?.matchmakerDelegate = self
        viewController.present(mmvc!, animated: true, completion: { _ in })
    }
```

**Objective-C**

```
- (void)findMatchWithMinPlayers:(int)minPlayers maxPlayers:(int)maxPlayers
                 viewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                       delegate:(id<GameKitHelperDelegate>)delegate {

    if (!_enableGameCenter) return;

    _matchStarted = NO;
    self.match = nil;
    _delegate = delegate;
    [viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

    GKMatchRequest *request = [[GKMatchRequest alloc] init];
    request.minPlayers = minPlayers;
    request.maxPlayers = maxPlayers;

    GKMatchmakerViewController *mmvc =
        [[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithMatchRequest:request];
    mmvc.matchmakerDelegate = self;

    [viewController presentViewController:mmvc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The only other thing I can thing of that may have been different was this:

**Objective-C**

```
+ (instancetype)sharedGameKitHelper
{
    static GameKitHelper *sharedGameKitHelper;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
      sharedGameKitHelper = [[GameKitHelper alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedGameKitHelper;
}
```

**Swift**
And instead I just used a global var called `sharedGameKitHelper` and anytime in the code where they used `[GameKitHelper sharedGameKitHelper]` I used `sharedGameKitHelper`. They described the purpose of that method as creating a "singleton object" of the GameKitHelper class.

If you find nothing wrong with those, here's a full Pastebin of both of my "GameKitHelper" classes, which contain all the GameKit code. 
[objectice-c](https://pastebin.com/csxXTyfW)          [swift](https://pastebin.com/1RJUEPMA) 
I've checked every method multiple times and restarted the project from scratch, so I must have some hole in my knowledge of objective-c conversions. Thanks for any help you can give!